# iOS - Take screenshot before app crashes

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, crash, screenshot

Is there any way to take a screenshot right before the app crashes. I'm using this code to take a screenshot, but how to know when the app will crash ?

```
func screenShotMethod() {

    //Create the UIImage
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(view.frame.size)
    view.layer.renderInContext(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
}
```

Comment: in native you can use test cases for this , but in your question is you need the screen shot then you need to go for some third party test cases , those are shown the image and video also where/when crash is occur.

Comment: You can't. You can install an exception handler, but they're very limited. Your best bet is probably to have a debug mode where you save images or log information constantly. When the app crashes, the last thing written hopefully has the information you need.

Answer (score 1):

**AppDelegate:**

```
func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    //that methiod is called when app is going to crash
}
```

Comment: when i write the above code inside this function in AppDelegate, i get 'use of unresolved identifier 'view'